# javascript how to check if object which includes arrays is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, is-empty

I have an object, which itself includes arrays

how to check if such object is empty or not in javascript (or in Angular.js) ?

[please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWJt7.png)

Comment: Please show an example of the object you want to test.

Comment: I would think that if an object includes an array, then by definition, the object is not empty.  It is not clear what you're actually asking without more detail and some object definition examples.

Comment: What does "empty" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to see if the object has any enumerable properties:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
   if (!obj || typeof obj !== "object") {
      throw new Error("Must pass object");
   }
   return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```

Or, if you don't want the type checking:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```

Comment: if do not need to check if it an object or not, as it will always be an object ))

Comment: @AnnieAlan - So just remove that step then.

Comment: so if my object name is myObject, I should check this way? if(Object.keys(myObject).length === 0) 
{
  ?

Comment: @AnnieAlan - `Object.keys(obj)` returns an array of enumerable properties.  If that array length is zero, then there are no enumerable properties in the object (thus it is empty).

Comment: or just if(myObject.length === 0) ?

Comment: @AnnieAlan - No.  Plain objects, don't have a `.length` property.  Arrays do, but not plain objects.

Comment: hey, thank you very much ^^ it works great!  (:

Comment: @AnnieAlan - Since it appears you may be new here, you may want to know that when your question gets answered, you can indicate that to the community and to the person who supplied the answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.  Reputation points will lead to more privileges on the site as you earn enough.

Comment: yes I know, I have tried to vote, but it says I can only vote if I earn a total of 15 reputation :/

Comment: @AnnieAlan - That's what it takes to upvote (clicking the up arrow).  Since you wrote the question, you can "accept' an answer by clicking the checkmark even as a brand new user.

Comment: ok, done :)
I have another question regarding objects and arrays, if I ask with another post, will you help? :D

Comment: @AnnieAlan - Maybe.  It depends upon whether it's a well written, clear question that I know the answer to.